How do I get Ubuntu to recognize 22.04.5 LTS unstead of 22.04.1 (non LTS)?
I have a laptop/notebook with 22.04.5 LTS installed (via Settings > About):

But it doesn't show up as 22.04.5 LTS when I do uname -a in the terminal.
george@gwg-laptop:~$ uname -a 
Linux gwg-laptop 6.8.0-47-generic #47~**22.04.1-Ubuntu** SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Oct  2 16:16:55 UTC 2 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I have two questions:



How can I get Ubuntu to recognize my actual 22.04.5 LTS version?




How can I get Ubuntu to install the 'HWE' version?




The command uname is showing PACKAGING INFORMATION when it tells you 22.04.1, and NOT release details; uname being a command related to the kernel and not your release.  The HWE kernel for 22.04.5 is 6.8, the GA kernel for 22.04.5 is 5.15 so you've got what it appears you want already.

Classic new-user misunderstanding: Both 22.04.1 and 22.04.5 are BOTH simply 22.04. the extra .1 and .5 are merely respins of the installer so you're not downloading extra GB of old bugfixes and security patches. They are not new releases. They do not have new versions of software. As long as sudo apt update and sudo apt upgrade complete without error, you will always be running the "latest" 22.04.

The command uname is showing PACKAGING INFORMATION when it tells you 22.04.1, and NOT release details; uname being a command intended to show kernel details (not your release information).
The HWE kernel for 22.04.5 is 6.8, the GA kernel for 22.04.5 is 5.15 so you've got what it appears you want already.
As @ubfan1 suggested, a good means to know what you're running is using the lsb_release command (do note as almost none of us use Linux Standard Base, thus no modules being available is expected)
guiverc@d7050-next:~$   lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 24.10
Release:        24.10
Codename:       oracular

My current install is running Ubuntu 24.10 codename oracular. Another way of looking is cat /etc/os-release too.
For details on HWE/GA kernel stack, please refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack (these kernel stack options exist only for LTS releases, so won't exist on my non-LTS system)

Thank you 'guiverc', I was unsure but now I know!

We all start somewhere, and either learn by doing, or in factual details like asking questions & seeking information. Enjoy your journey, and don't stop learning ! @GWGeorge007

lsb_release -a. Will indicate release for the patch level.
